# This compiled function won't mint beyond integer 53?

Tags: solidity

Using Remix.Ethereum IDE, on the LearnEth module. This exercise is about Error Handling. I have compiled and deployed the errorHandling.sol script to JSVM successfully.

However, when I interact with the mint function in the IDE (inputting account number and different integers)-- I am able to successfully 'mint' from 1-53, but NOT beyond that-- it fails and gives this error message:

For the life of me, I can't understand why the other numbers would work and not this one, given the limits? I would appreciate any guidance.

Sorry if there is an obvious error or misunderstanding-- very new here.

````
contract Coin {
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    constructor() public {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(minter == receiver, 'Cannot Mint! Minter is not contract Creator!');
        require(amount < (1 * (10^60)), 'Amount requested too High for minting');
        balances[receiver] = amount;
    }
    
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(balances[minter] >= amount, 'Coin balance to low for transaction!');
        balances[minter] = -amount;
        balances[receiver] = amount;
        emit Sent(minter, receiver, amount);
    } 
    
}```

>  [vm] from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: Coin.mint(address,uint256)
> 0xEf9...10eBfvalue: 0 weidata: 0x40c...00036logs: 0hash: 0xc0a...40b8b
> transact to Coin.mint errored: VM error: revert.
> 
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason
> provided by the contract: "Amount requested too High for minting".
> Debug the transaction to get more information.
````

Comment: the second require inside the "mint" function has been triggered

require is a restriction, if it is not met, the transaction fails

Comment: Thanks, yeah I understand that-- but doesn't explain why it's failing partially I.e. minting 1-53 and not beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this condition.

```
require(amount < (1 * (10^60)), 'Amount requested too High for minting');
```

Which throws an exception, effectively reverting the transaction, if the value of `amount` is greater or equal 54.

You can simplify the `(1 * (10^60))` expression as `10^60`. Mind that in the Solidity syntax, this is **not** "10 to the power of 60" - it's "10 [XOR](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays) 60" (which results in 54).

If you want to calculate "10 to the power of 60", the syntax is `10 ** 60`.

Comment: Brilliant— thanks for answering this, your answer makes sense and I verified the code works now: replacing (1 * (10^60)) with (10 ** 60), I 'm able to mint passing 1-2000 as test-range inputs successfully.

Comment: As a separate follow-up question about this code:

I minted 200 multiple times to the same address.

When using the check balance function for the address that minted however, only the most recent number minted is stored (I.e. 200 even if I passed 200, 200, 200, 2000 consecutively to the mint function)

Is Solidity not storing each value minted to the address if using the mint function multiple times?

Comment: @codelace This line in the `mint()` function **sets** the `balances[receiver]` value (i.e. overwriting any previously set value) to `amount`: `balances[receiver] = amount;`. If you want to **increase** the `balances[receiver]` value by `amount`, you can use the `+=` operator: `balances[receiver] += amount;` (which is a short for `balances[receiver] = balances[receiver] + amount`).

Comment: Updated and confirmed this code change works- learned a lot here. Thanks a ton for your help with these basics!

Answer (score 0):

Question answered. I want to record the logic operation here for completeness:

When comparing two bytes (10 and 60) in a bit-wise XOR operation (I.e. both bits have to be different to get a 1), I yielded 54:

**255:** `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`   = (128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1) = **255**

---

**60:** `0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0` = (0 + 0 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 0 + 0) = **60**

**10:** `0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0` = (0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 0) = **10**

---

**60 XOR 10:** `0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0` = (0 + 0 + 32 + 16 + 0 + 4 + 2 + 0) = **54**